# Lists in Python

Tags: python

I noticed that you can multiply list by scalar but the behavior is weird 
If I multiply:

```
[2,3,4] * 3
```

I get:
 `[2,3,4,2,3,4,2,3,4`]
I understand the results but what it's good for? Is there any other weird operations like that?

Comment: why down vote? i searched the site and didn't find an answer what does it good for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main purpose of this operand is for initialisation. For example, if you want to initialize a list with 20 equal numbers you can do it using a for loop:

```
arr=[]
for i in range(20):
    arr.append(3)
```

An alternative way will be using this operator:

```
arr = [3] * 20
```

More weird and normal list operation on lists you can find here http://www.discoversdk.com/knowledge-base/using-lists-in-python

Answer (score 1):

The operation has a use of creating arrays initialized with some value.

For example `[5]*1000` means "create an array of length 1000 initialized with 5".

If you want to multiply each element by 3, use

```
map(lambda x: 3*x, arr)
```

Comment: and its just for initialisation? why python writer did so weird operator instead of a simple init function?